# Django - How do you assign 'feedback' for each 'user' to a single 'assignment'? (Many to one)

Tags: django, django-models

I have three models 'User', 'Assignment' and 'Feedback'. I am trying to setup a OneToMany assignment that can be accessed/viewed by all user accounts, where feedback can then be applied but only viewed by a OneToOneField user account. Here is some code to help explain what is currently happening.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

# Create your models here.
class UserProfile(models.Model):
USER_TYPE_CHOICES = (
    ('Student', 'Student'),
    ('Lecturer', 'Lecturer'),
    ('Admin', 'Admin'),
) 
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
uni_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
type_user = models.CharField(max_length=20, 
default='s',choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES)
description = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
city = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
website = models.URLField(default='')
phone = models.IntegerField(default=0)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image', blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username

def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
if kwargs['created']:
    user_profile = 
UserProfile.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'])

post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)


# Assignment model
class Assignment(models.Model):
assignment_title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
assignment_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
user = models.ManyToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

# Feedback model
class Feedback(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I thought about maybe a foreign key connecting the assignments to a OneToOne field in the feedback model, but I'm really not sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more about what you want to achieve here?

Comment: I am building a student feedback system, where I have student's and lecture's. I want an admin to be able to create assignments (setup in the assignment model) which apply to all users. I then want to be able to add feedback to that assignment that only the user logged in can see (so that it applies to them specifically).

Answer (score 0):

I would think that you'd want to relate the feedback to a specific assignment (of which there could be many), so you need an assignment foreign key in the `Feedback` model. Also, you'd need `User` as a foreign key rather than a one-to-one relationship as this would restrict you to one feedback per user.

```
class Feedback(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    assignment = models.ForeignKey(Assignment, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

If a user can only get one feedback per assignment, specify this in the `Feedback` model:

```
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('assignment', 'user')
```

Extend the `Feedback` model with the actual feedback (grade, comments etc.) and possibly with a field for the originator of the feedback.

You can then create a view that only displays feedback for the `request.user`. 
The [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial03/#s-write-views-that-actually-do-something) offers quite a bit on views, as do [many](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Generic_views) [other](https://leportella.com/english/2017/11/24/classe-based-views-on-django.html) [helpful](https://www.simplifiedpython.net/django-views-tutorial-creating-view/) [resources](https://www.pythoncentral.io/writing-simple-views-for-your-first-python-django-application/).

In `Assignment`, as an assignment can be given to multiple students and students will get multiple assignments in the course of their studies, you'd need a many to many relationship to `User`:

```
users = ManyToManyField(User)
```

(There is no `ManyToOneField` btw, that would be a `ForeignKey`.)

Comment: Last thing - how do I bring all this into the html, I am a little unsure on how views work?